# oledb provider for sqlite

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, oledb

I faced a problem using sqlite3 in .net (c#). I can't find a suitable oledb provider for sqlite. I found one ( http://cherrycitysoftware.com/ccs/Providers/ProvSQLite.aspx ) but here you have to wait for few weeks to activate it (at least to get a free activation).

Is there any other oledb providers for sqlite in .net ?

Comment: http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

Comment: If I understood correctly System.Data.Sqlite it's not an oledb provider. I tried to use it in my connection string (@"Provider=System.Data.Sqlite; Data Source=" + _dbFilePath + ";Version=3;") but I am getting error The 'System.Data.Sqlite' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Comment: Just a guess but, http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/, I believe you have to buy it though

Comment: One other possibility, http://adodotnetsqlite.sourceforge.net/documentation/SQLiteConnection/ConnectionString.php

Answer (score 0):

Some guys seem to confuse ADO.NET Drivers and OLEDB-Providers.
This [32Bit OLEDB-Provider](https://github.com/mobileFX/SQLiteOLEDB) worked for me